# Arduino String Compare Issues

Tags: string, arduino, string-comparison

I am having an issue with comparing strings in my program. I receive in serial data and save it to a string:

```
void serialEvent() {
    if(!stringComplete){
         while (Serial.available()) {
              // get the new byte:
              char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
              // add it to the inputString:
              inputString += inChar;
              // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
              // so the main loop can do something about it:
              if (inChar == '\n') {
              stringComplete = true;
              Serial.println("COMPLETE");

 }
```

I then do a compare on the string that was stored from the serialEvent function:

```
void setCMD(String a){
         if(a == "01*00"){
             busACTIVE=0;
             // clear the string:
             inputString = "";
             stringComplete = false;
             }
         else if(a.equals("01*01")){
              busACTIVE=1;
             // clear the string:
             inputString = "";
             stringComplete = false;
```

}
I have several else if statements and then a else statement at the end:

```
else{
    Serial.println("Command not Found");
    Serial.println(a);
   // clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
    }
```

I tried both == operator and equals() and neither will compare properly. below is a serial output:
[Serial Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELAV9.jpg)

As you can see one of my comparison statements looks for 01*01 and that is also what you see in the serial output window but the if statement did not equate to true. Can anyone help figure out why this is not working. Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add that String a in the setCMD function is called in the main loop as setCMD(inputString);

Comment: You add the '\n' to inputString so the test fails

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this:

```
inputString += inChar;
// if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
// so the main loop can do something about it:
if (inChar == '\n') {
    stringComplete = true;
    Serial.println("COMPLETE");
}
```

into this:

```
// if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
// so the main loop can do something about it:
if (inChar == '\n') {
    stringComplete = true;
    Serial.println("COMPLETE");
}
else
    inputString += inChar;
```

The reason is that if you are comparing `"01*00"` with `"01*00\n"` and, of course, the comparison fails.

Anyway I'd avoid using variable-sized buffers. I definitely prefer using fixed-size buffers for performance reasons. And also because microcontrollers are... micro! Don't waste their scarce resources on `malloc`s and `free`s...

Comment: I tried you edit but it did not work. I added \n to the comparison string and it worked. Also thanks for your suggestions. I am not new to programming so I appreciate the tips you added.

Comment: Did you also remove the line `inputString += inChar;` as I did? Cause... that is the only possible mistake ;)